# Random.nextInt creates out of bound integers

Tags: java, android, random

I am trying a basic app in android. The following code prints out 32, 33, 34 and 35 values for the randomNum. Why is it behaving this way ?

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);final String[] lyrics = {"Caught in a Landslide!","No"," Escape","From Reality..."};
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random rando = new Random();
            int randomNum = rando.nextInt(4);
            textView.setText(randomNum + ' ' + lyrics[randomNum]);
        }
    });
```

P.S. - It is working fine and printing out the values from lyrics array only. just the randomNum is printed weirdly!
\

Answer (score 7):

The expression `randomNum + ' '` is evaluated first, before the concatenation to the string `lyrics[random]`, because it's evaluated from left to right.  Both values are promoted to `int`.  The `char` `' '` is promoted to `int`, resulting in the value `32`.  The random number (0-3) is added to it, yielding a range of 32-35.

Force string concatenation to work properly by adding the `String` `" "` instead of the `char` `' '`.

```
randomNum + " " + lyrics[randomNum]
```

Comment: That's it! You could also use `String.format()` which is less error prone, like this `String.format("%d %s", randomNum, lyrics[randomNum])`

Comment: @rgettman you are fast brother! :) thanks for the clarification. You are right!